# How to GROUP BY total amount for all items in order in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I need to calculate total amount for all items in the order, I used `STRING_AGG()` but the output divided the amounts in multiple rows.

This is the SELECT statement :

```
    SELECT b.order_id as 'Order Id',
       string_agg(e.testname,CHAR(13)) as 'Test',
       string_agg(d.PRICE,CHAR(13))  as 'Price',
       string_agg(d.test_vat,CHAR(13))  as '15% Vat',
       sum(convert(float,d.TOTAL_AMOUNT)) as 'Total'
     
  FROM patients a , lab_orders b ,customers c , order_details d , labtests e  
  where a.patient_no = b.patient_no 
  and b.custid = c.custid
  and b.order_id = d.order_id 
  and d.testid = e.testid
  and b.ORDER_ID=2000000272
  
  group by   b.order_id , d.TOTAL_AMOUNT
```

The output :

```
Order Id    Test                                 Price       15% Vat        Total
2000000272  (TSH) Free T3 (FT3) Free T4 (FT4)   90 90 90    13.5 13.5 13.5  310.5
2000000272  SGPT(ALT) SGOT (AST)                40 40       6 6             92
2000000272  Patient Time (PT)                   60          9               69
```

Why the total divided to 3 rows because of GROUP BY how to fix this and show the total for all items 310.5+92+69 = 471.5  in one row only.

Comment: As a best practice I highly recommend using modern, explicit joins, rather than those old style implicit joins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the total amount from the `group by` clause:

```
group by b.order_id --, d.total_amount
```

This guarantees just one row per `order_id`, while, on the other hand, having `total_amount` in the `group by` clause breaks into a new row for every different value of tuple `(order_id, total_amount)`.

Side notes:

- use standard joins! old-school, implicit joins are legacy syntax, that should not be used in new code
- don't use single quotes for identifiers; use square brackets, or better yet, identifiers that do not require quoting
- don't store numbers as strings

So:

```
select lo.order_id
    string_agg(lt.testname, char(13))    as Test,
    string_agg(od.price, char(13))       as Price,
    string_agg(od.test_vat, char(13))    as [15% Vat],
    sum(convert(float, od.total_amount)) as Total
from patients p, 
inner join lab_orders lo    on p.patient_no = lo.patient_no 
inner join locustomers c    on lo.custid = c.custid
inner join order_details od on lo.order_id = od.order_id 
inner join labtests lt      on od.testid = lt.testid
where lo.order_id = 2000000272
group by lo.order_id
```

Comment: before when i removed d.total_amount from group by its show error that d.total_amount should be in group by but now its not show the error and working fine thank you :)